# Seeking best way to preserve params from the last http exchange to use in a future exchange?

Tags: grails

I have a controller function which I am using to do two things, render a template, and use the Grails exporter plugin to export some XML, the first time this function is called:

```
def individualsReportingSearch() {
        params.selectedBatch = selectedBatch
        def resultList = recordSearchService.individualSearch(params)
        if(params?.format && params.format == "xml"){
            response.contentType = grailsApplication.config.grails.mime.types[params.format]
            response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=IndividualRecords.${params.extension}")
            exportService.export(params.format, response.outputStream,resultList, [:], [:])
        }
        else {
            render(template: 'indivReportingSearchResults', model: [resultList: resultList, resultCount: resultList.size()])
        }
    }
```

the else clause will execute and a template will render which will show a table, the table has an export button below it which I use to export the records being displayed in that table, this is the GSP tag for the export "button".

```
<div id="exportBar"><export:formats formats="['xml']" action="individualsReportingSearch"/></div>
```

The issue is that the second time this method is called to export the records currently being displayed in the table, it's exporting all the records in the database because the filtration params aren't there which were there when the first time it was called.  So, the template table might be displaying two records because it was built using filtered results in a variable called 'resultList' but when I export, all the records get exported even the ones that aren't being displayed in the table. How can I preserve those 'old params' that were used to built the template in the last http exchange so that I may add them to the params map in the second call to this controller method when invoked from the export button? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can stick them in the session, in a variable (say old-params) and have the second call use those if they are available.